# Stop or verification in a sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question. I have this sql :

```
SELECT * FROM `plnning`  
WHERE (`begin` <= "2017-01-31 10:00:00" AND "2017-01-31 10:00:00" < `end`) 
OR (`begin` < "2017-02-01 10:00:00" AND "2017-02-01 10:00:00" <= `end`) 
OR ("2017-01-31 10:00:00" <= `begin` AND "2017-02-01 10:00:00" >= `end`)
AND source = 2
```

When I execute the sql I have this data :

```
id        begin                   end                  source
1        2017-01-31 10:00:00    2017-02-01 10:00:00      1
```

Strange because the source = 1 but in sql I search source = 2, I suppose that from `OR` in clause. How I can solve this ? Please help me. Thx in advance and sorry for my english

Answer (score 3):

you should put all **OR** condition in bracket only. see I have put all condition into bracket

```
SELECT * FROM `plnning`  
    WHERE  ( (`begin` <= "2017-01-31 10:00:00" AND "2017-01-31 10:00:00" < `end`) 
    OR (`begin` < "2017-02-01 10:00:00" AND "2017-02-01 10:00:00" <= `end`) 
    OR ("2017-01-31 10:00:00" <= `begin` AND "2017-02-01 10:00:00" >= `end`) )
    AND source = 2
```

Answer (score 3):

you should try like  this

```
SELECT * FROM `plnning`  
WHERE ((`begin` <= "2017-01-31 10:00:00" AND "2017-01-31 10:00:00" < `end`) 
OR (`begin` < "2017-02-01 10:00:00" AND "2017-02-01 10:00:00" <= `end`) 
OR ("2017-01-31 10:00:00" <= `begin` AND "2017-02-01 10:00:00" >= `end`))
AND source = 2
```